# Difficulty in using iwconfig, can i get full command to start a virtuall wireless network?

Tags: wireless, networking, playonlinux

I came to know that iwconfig does the work for sharing the virtual wireless network but I have difficulty in using the command. I have no idea how to use this command. I felt harder even after reading the manual. So could someone provide the command through which I can easily start the virtual wireless network for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need following tools to start the wireless network,

> ```
> ifconfig: Enable your wireless device.
> iwlist: List the available wireless access points.
> iwconfig: Configure your wireless connection.
> dhclient: Get your IP Address via dhcp.
> wpa_supplicant: For use with WPA authentication.
> ```

Detailed steps are given [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/374514-control-wireless-on-the-linux-desktop-with-these-tools)

> Let's take a look at how this is done when you are connecting to a
>   non-WPA authentication-based wireless network.
>
> Now that you have confirmed they are installed start off with the
>   command:
>
> ifconfig wlan0 up
>
> Where wlan0 is the name of your wireless device (this is most often
>   the default). The above command will bring your wireless device up so
>   it is ready to use. The next phase is to scan for any wireless access
>   points with the command:
>
> iwlist wlan0 scan
>
> From the output of the scan you should see a line (or lines) like:
>
> ESSID: "NETWORK_NAME"
>
> Where NETWORK_NAME is the name of an available wireless network.
>
> Now that you have your network name (and you know it's available) you
>   can connect to that network with the command:
>
> iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_NAME key WIRELESS_KEY
>
> Where NETWORK_NAME is the name of the network you want to connect to
>   and WIRELESS_KEY is the security key for that network. NOTE: The
>   iwconfig command defaults to HEX values for wireless keys. If you need
>   to use ascii you have to prepend the "s" prefix to your key like so:
>
> **iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_NAME key s:WIRELESS_KEY**
>
> With your connection made, you now have to get an IP address for your
>   machine using the dhclient command like:
>
> dhclient wlan0

You can also look at [hostapd](http://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/). 
Hope this'll help.